# SQL - Set column value depending on another column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have my database with the following key columns

[image: My database layout]

What I would like to do is using the information provided create 2 new columns that contains a value based on 2 other columns.

1) A 'win' column - This is if 'pos' = 1 then value will be (BSP - 1) - EG One for Billy will read 1.06 else it will read "-1"

2)A 'diditplace' Column - this is if 'Placed' = 1 then value will be (place - 1) - EG One for Billy will read 0.27 else it will read "-1"

Comment: Hint:  `CASE` expressions.

Comment: If you're still struggling, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET    newColumn1 = CASE pos WHEN 1 THEN 'BSCP - 1' ELSE '-1' END,
       newColumn2 = CASE placeId WHEN 1 THEN 'place - 1' ELSE '-1' END
```

If you want to add new columns pragmatically add this before:

```
ALTER myTable
      ADD COLUMN newColumn1 VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
      ADD COLUMN newColumn2 VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
```

Replace `newColumn1` and `newColumn2` with your desired column names.